# Applying methods to multiple datasets in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use the `.assign` method with multiple lambda functions to multiple datasets. So far, I've tried with a for loop without success:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(5),
                  'b': np.arange(5)})

b = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(5,10),
                  'b': np.arange(5,10)})

for data in [a,b]:
    data.assign(c = lambda x: x.a+x.b,
                d = lambda x: x.a^x.b)
```

Edit:

The following doesn't work either:

```
for data in [a,b]:
    data = data.assign(c = lambda x: x.a+x.b,
                d = lambda x: x.a^x.b)
```

Comment: That doesn't work because `asign` doesn't modify the existing dataframe in place, but instead return a new dataframe object.

Comment: I guess that in practice you want a solution that works for any number of dataframes?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297292/apply-a-for-loop-to-multiple-dataframes-in-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why this doesn't work is that `asign` doesn't modify the existing dataframe in place, but instead return a new dataframe object.

What you want to do is to apply the same function to several objects, that's exactly what the `map` function is made for:

```py
def assign(df):
    return df.assign(c = lambda x: x.a+x.b,
                     d = lambda x: x.a^x.b)

(a, b) = map(assign, (a,b))
```

A more general solution is the following:

```py
# Imagine we don't have control over the following line of code:
dataframes = (a, b)

# We can still use the same solution: 
dataframes = tuple(map(assign, dataframes))
print(dataframes[0])
```

Concerning your **edit**, the reason why this doesn't work is a bit more interesting. It may not seem obvious in your code, but it will be in this one:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
data = a
data = [4, 5, 6]
print(data)
```

Here there it is clear that this output `[4, 5, 6]` and not `[1, 2, 3]`.

What happen in both your code and this last one is the same:

1. `data = a`: `data` is binded to the same object as `a` (resp. `b`)
2. `data = ...`: creates a new binding, leaving the existing binding of `a` untouched (as `data` was only binded to the same object as `a`, `data` never was `a`).

In the end, `for data in [a, b]:` **doesn't mean** that `data` will be an **alias** for `a` (resp. `b`) during the next iteration. (Which is what you may expect when writing this.) Instead `for data in [a, b]:` simply is equivalent to:

```py
data = a
# 1st iteration
data = b
# 2nd iteration
```

Comment: thanks! I edited the question because I forgot to put a `data = data.assign...`

Comment: You should let your code as it was otherwise people reading the answer and the question won't understand what is going on  ^^

Comment: I edited too, to have a full answer to this question. I hope it makes sense, let me know if you have any question as I think this is an interesting question/answer to get right and clear.