# Searching for a string in a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I have a list of dataframes, called `list_models`.

```
list_models=[df_gl,df_reg, df_in]
```

Each df consists of the same columns: `Title, URL, Status`

I am looking for a loop which looks for a string in `Status` and updates `list_models`.

```
list_models=[df[df['Status'].str.contains('In-depth', na=False)] |
         [df['Status'].str.contains('Approve', na=False)] 
         for df in list_models]
```

This code won't update the dfs in `list_models` and I don't understand why.
Can anyone explain it to me?

Apparently someone already posted a similar question. However the answer is not really comprehensive, at least for me.
[Apply a for loop to multiple DataFrames in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297292/apply-a-for-loop-to-multiple-dataframes-in-pandas#38297645)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `df | [df]` in your `for-loop`. `pat` argument of [pandas.Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) can detect multiple string at one time like

```py
list_models = [df[df['Status'].str.contains('In-depth|Approve', na=False)]
               for df in list_models]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the problem explained above remains. The code will not update the dfs in my list.

Comment: @chajamalka What's the result of `df['Status'].str.contains('In-depth|Approve', na=False)` of each dataframe in list?

Comment: The loop should filter out those rows containing the words 'In-depth' and 'Approve' for each df. However, after looping through the list I can see that the filter was not applied.

Comment: @chajamalka If you want to filter out. Use `df[~df['Status'].str.contains('In-depth|Approve', na=False)]`.

Comment: @chajamalka I ask the output of `df['Status'].str.contains('In-depth|Approve', na=False)` is to ensure if this statement runs correctly. If it is all false, then this means your `Status` column doesn't contain `In-depth` or `Approve`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231770/discussion-between-chajamalka-and-ynjxsjmh).

Comment: @chajamalka *This person has exactly the same problem.* It is obvious for me why that person faces the problem. Now I couldn't produce your problem. I ask the output of `df['Status'].str.contains('In-depth|Approve', na=False)` for more info for me to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The loop above stores copies of the dataframes in the list, but does not alter them as I intended to.

Unpacking the list does the trick.

```
df_gl,df_reg, df_in=list_models
```